# Obtaining pixel value from 16-bit tiff images using magick package in R

Tags: r, imagemagick, wolfram-mathematica, tiff

Does anyone know how to obtain the pixel value for each channel (RGB) from 16-bit tiff images using the magick package in R? Currently I am using Mathematica to perform this operation, because I could not find an equivalent way to doing it in mathematica.

I have tried to read the pixel value from the image-magick package and the results is a raw type (e.g. "ff"). I used the function rawToNum (package "pack") to convert the raw type to numeric and the results is close to what I obtain using ImageDate function in Mathematica, but not exactly the same.

Comment: Have you tried `readTIFF` from the `tiff` package in R?  I have used it to get the RGB values for tiff images.

Answer (score 4):

You can also access the pixels as a numeric array with the `magick` package. The example is based on [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) from the package.

```
library(magick)

tiger <- image_read('http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg')
tiger_tiff <- image_convert(tiger, "tiff")

# Access data in raw format and convert to integer
tiger_array <- as.integer(tiger_tiff[[1]])
```

Then if check the dimension and type you get:

```
dim(tiger_array)
[1] 900 900   4
is.numeric(tiger_array)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about `R` at all, but I guess you can *"shell out"* and execute an external command, using `system()` or somesuch.

If, so, maybe you can use this. First, let's make a 16-bit TIFF file that is a gradient from red-blue just 10 pixels wide and 1 pixel tall:

```
convert -size 10x1 gradient:red-blue image.tiff
```

[image]

Now we can dump the pixels to a file using **ImageMagick**:

```
convert image.tiff rgb:image.rgb

# Now check its length - yes, 60 bytes = 10 pixels with 2 bytes each for RG &B
ls -l image.rgb
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  60 11 Jul 10:32 image.rgb
```

We can also write the data to `stdout` like this:

```
convert image.tiff rgb:-
```

and also look at it with 1 pixel per line (6 bytes)

```
convert image.tiff rgb:- | xxd -g 3 -c 6
00000000: ffff00 000000  ......   # Full Red, no Green, no Blue
00000006: 8de300 00721c  ....r.   # Lots of Red, no Green, a little Blue
0000000c: 1cc700 00e338  .....8
00000012: aaaa00 005555  ....UU
00000018: 388e00 00c771  8....q
0000001e: c77100 00388e  .q..8.
00000024: 555500 00aaaa  UU....
0000002a: e33800 001cc7  .8....
00000030: 721c00 008de3  r.....
00000036: 000000 00ffff  ......   # No Red, no Green, full Blue
```

I'm hoping you can do something like that in `R`, with:

```
system("convert image.tif rgb:-")
```

---

Another way of dumping the pixels might be with `Perl` to slurp the entire file and then unpack the contained unsigned shorts and print them one per line:

```
convert image.tiff rgb: | perl -e 'my $str=do{local $/; <STDIN>}; print join("\n",unpack("v*",$str)),"\n";'
```

**Sample Output**

```
65535      # Full Red 
0          # No Green
0          # No Blue
58253      # Lots of Red
0          # No Green
7282       # A little Blue
50972      # Moderate Red
0
14563
43690
0
21845
36408
0
29127
29127
0
36408
21845
0
43690
14563
0
50972
7282
0          # No Green
58253      # Lots of Blue
0          # No Red
0          # No Green
65535      # Full Blue
```

---

Another way of seeing the data may be using `od` and `awk` like this:

```
convert image.tiff rgb: | od -An -tuS | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}'
65535
0
0
58253
0
7282
50972
0
14563
43690
0
21845
36408
0
29127
29127
0
36408
21845
0
43690
14563
0
50972
7282
0
58253
0
0
65535
```

where the `-An` suppresses printing of the address, and the `-tuS` says the type of the data is unsigned short.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a slightly simpler way in ImageMagick would be to use the txt: output format.

Using Mark Setchell's image:

```
convert -size 10x1 gradient:red-blue image.tiff
```

Using TXT: as

```
convert image.tiff txt: | sed -n 's/^.*[(]\(.*\)[)].*[#].*$/\1/p'
```

Produces:

```
65535,0,0
58253,0,7282
50972,0,14563
43690,0,21845
36408,0,29127
29127,0,36408
21845,0,43690
14563,0,50972
7282,0,58253
0,0,65535
```

or Using TXT: to include the pixel coordinates

```
convert image.tiff txt: | sed -n 's/^\(.*[)]\).*[#].*$/\1/p'
```

Produces:

```
0,0: (65535,0,0)
1,0: (58253,0,7282)
2,0: (50972,0,14563)
3,0: (43690,0,21845)
4,0: (36408,0,29127)
5,0: (29127,0,36408)
6,0: (21845,0,43690)
7,0: (14563,0,50972)
8,0: (7282,0,58253)
9,0: (0,0,65535)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. The best answer I found was given by a student of mine using the package raster:

```
library(raster)
img <- stack(filename)
x <- as.matrix(raster(img, 1)) # here we specify the layer 1, 2 or 3
```

The only issue is that the function as.matrix of the package raster may be confused with the one from the base package, so it may be necessary to specify raster::as.matrix.

Answer (score 0):

@Nate_A gave the answer, but three cents short of a dollar.

After

```
dim(tiger_array)
[1] 900 900   4
```

You get each channel color of first pixel by

```
tiger_array[1,1,1] # red
tiger_array[1,1,2] # green
tiger_array[1,1,3] # blue
```

Or if you prefer between 0 - 255

```
tiger_array[1,1,1]*255
tiger_array[1,1,2]*255
tiger_array[1,1,3]*255
```